# Databasename in SQLCE.EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework

Did anyone knows how can i affect the name of the database in SQLCE.EntityFramework ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i got it ;)

I had to override the constructor of my DbContext Class like this

public class ProductCatalog : DbContext
{

```
public ProductCatalog()
   : base("MyProductCatalog")
{

}

public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

}

i have found the solution on
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160502112606/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/07/14/ctp4piwalkthrough.aspx)

thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, if I understand your question correctly.

```
Dim ef As New EntityConnection(New MetadataWorkspace(New String() {"res://*/"}, New Assembly() {Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()}), **New SqlConnection("Server=yourserver; user id=yourid;password=yourpassword;Database=yourdb;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"))**


dim ctx as New YourContext(ef)
```

Comment: Sorry that i could react so late. Maybe this is the right answer. At the moment i cant check it out. I will try that later and come back to let you know. Thanks!

Comment: I have changed the Connectionstring like you mentioned but it doesnt solve the problem. 

Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlConnectionFactory("Server=Servername\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MVCTestDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;");